# Pattern for spam edits on blender.se

Tags: discussion, edits, spam, rejected-edits, spam-detection

After reviewing [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/11434) edit, I knew I had seen spam on that post before. Turns out that, after some digging and filtering out the edits on tag wikis, that spam on the [blender stack exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) site seems to target the same places that have been spammed before.

**Here are the numbers**
**229** total rejected edits
minus **39** on tag wikis (early in the sites history there were a lot of edits to tag wikis that got rejected for not being up to standard.)
Leaves **190** rejected edits on questions and answers.
There are **20** spam edits on [Make a seamless, continuing texture on two separate models](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8182/2217) (nearly all of which are on [vader's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8183/2217) answer)
Another **18** spam edits on [How can I automatically generate vertex groups for an armature?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/782/2217)

**38** spam edit on those two questions alone which makes up **20%** of all rejected edits on questions and answers.

What is it that makes spammers go back to those 2 answers?
What can SE do to predict this kind of activity, and block it?
Are there similar patterns on other SE sites?

Answer (score 6):

Those posts are small enough that a specific protection mechanism against replacing the complete content of the post in a suggested edit doesn't apply. If a spammer tried that stuff on a longer post, it would simply be rejected automatically.

The best way to stop spammy suggested edits to those specific posts is to make them a bit longer, I think the threshold was 400 characters. There are also other mechanisms that will block anonymous edits from the same source if multiple edits are declined as spam.